# How to install MSI to custom directory using msiexec?

Tags: windows, installation, powershell, windows-installer, wix

Here's my attempt to install `.msi` using `msiexec` in Administrative PowerShell on Windows 10.

I've made it 7 times for each of 2 drives, `C:` and `D:` (14 total) with different arguments in place of `ARG` and the same desirable path value.

Template: `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> msiexec /i D:\users\username\downloads\soft\publisher\softwarename\software.msi /passive ARG="D:\Soft\publisher\softwarename"`

`ARG`s:

- `TARGETDIR`, `INSTALLDIR`, `INSTALLPATH`, `INSTALLFOLDER`, `INSTALLLOCATION`, `APPLICATIONFOLDER`, `APPDIR`

  - When running on the same drive as
    set in the parameter: installs on this drive in a default folder
    (e.g. `D:\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.81\`)
  - When running from a
    differnet drive: seems to do nothing

Is there a workaround to this behavior?

**Update 1**

Tested it on another `.msi` package (Blender 2.81), because previous was built incorrectly. None of the argument names listed above did the trick. Every install even from a `D:` drive was on default folder on `C:`.

**Update 2**

For Blender 2.81, as, I suppose, for any `.msi` packed with `WiX`, it was `INSTALL_ROOT`. You could try `msiexec /lp! <msi_property_logfile> /i <msi_name>` for any `.msi` to find out the name of the installation path argument. Thanks to [YenForYang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7314180/yenforyang) and his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366480/detect-msi-parameters-for-unattended-install).

Comment: I think you misunderstand the way `msiexec /a` works. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564619/what-is-the-purpose-of-administrative-installation-initiated-using-msiexec-a and you will see that the parameter `/a` is not for installing at all.

Comment: @Robert thank you. Tested it with `/i` - now it does nothing in every occasion.

Comment: This question could lead to a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366480/detect-msi-parameters-for-unattended-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to properly work you need to perform these steps:

1. Get list of public properties used in your `.msi` installer:

   - `PS >.\YourAppInstaller.msi /lp! YourAppInstall.log`;
   - Cancel installation;
2. Find public properties in `.log` file generated in previous step;
3. Run your `.msi` with public property from command line:

   - If your property value contains spaces, then wrap it in backtick+quote pair (`` `" ``)
   - Example: `` PS >.\YourAppInstaller.msi YOUR_PROP=`"value with spaces`" ``

---

In case of Blender silent installation, to specify an install path, you need to call installer as follows (as an example):

`` .\blender-3.4.1-windows-x64.msi INSTALL_ROOT=`"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\`" ``

This way it will understand where you want it to be installed.